# idiotmatic construction for the phrase "people of same capability"

Tags: phrase-request

I am writing a blog, and my context is based on the phrase "when you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail".

The sentence construction I have is something like this,

> I have an ace in the hole, but I use it against people of same caliber/skill-set/talent, not against any random off the street.

Can somebody suggest an alternative for the pharse "people of the same caliber", in my given context.

This sentence feels very awkward to me overall. I won't mind a completely new sentence construction.

Answer (score 1):

A person who is your equal is your **peer**. "a person of the same age, status, or ability as another specified person."   You can also use **equals** in this sense.